# RabbitMQ dependency graph

Tags: graph, rabbitmq

I would like to know if there is any existing tool to generate dependency graph from JSON RabbitMQ broker definition.

I  looked into some open source GitHub Project and didn't find anything that create a full dependency graph for RabbitMQ (relations between queues - exchanges - routing keys...) .

It would be very interesting to have such tool to be able, through a graph, to see all rabbitMQ dependencies very quickly in a readable way.

For example :

Which exchange is routing messages to with queues (with routing keys indicated -> bindings)

Is anyone aware of any tools that does that out of the box ? Or the only way is to use tools such as neo4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found anything so far. So I decided to do it on my own with neo4j.

I took one rabbitMQ broker definition with shovel, queue, binding and exchange.

https://github.com/aaleks/rabbitmq-neo4j-dependency-graph

Comment: I cloned the project yesterday and run it against our broker definition file and I am very happy about the outcome. This is really helpful. Thank you for making this project available on github.

Comment: your welcome ! I quickly develop this at home and then continued at my company but I didn't had the chance to push the latest changes that handles the dlx,dlq and so on